# Register Assembly for MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So I was using asp.net/C# and now I'm updating my website to MVC.
So for my views I user Razor.

I want to use the Dev Express tools and I dont know how to add the following tag:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="DevExpress.Web.v12.2, Version=12.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=--------------"
Namespace="DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView" TagPrefix="dx" %>
```

So I would be able to use:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ......./>
```

I prefer this way instead of using:

```
@Html.DevExpress().....
```

because I cant find some of the properties as 'runat="server"'

Anyone already knows? I did some research and I couldnt find anything and maybe there is an explanation or other way to do it.

Comment: Try inserting `@using DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView` in your Razor view. [This](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument8163) could also be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing ASPX control tags with extension methods.

`<dx:ASPxGridView ......./>` is an ASPX control; it has nothing to do with Razor or MVC.

`Html.DevExpress` is an extension method that extends `HtmlHelper<T>`.
To use it, you simply need to [import the namespace that contains the method](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument9944), namely `DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView`.

You can import a namespace in a single view file using the `@using` directive, and you can import it globally by adding it to the `<pages>` tag in Views\Web.config.

Comment: @AnnArbor87: Yes; you can't.  It is fundamentally impossible to do that in Razor.

Comment: So I should change to aspx. So what is the benefit of Razor against ASPX?

Answer (score -2):

" So what is the benefit of Razor against ASPX?"  Less page events, more speed...Your requirements should decide the choice